define функции c++
Пытаюсь разобраться в уже существующем коде.
volatile char *Adr_Flash ; 
//объявление указателя типа char с квалификатором volatile.
#define R_Flash(A, D)      Adr_Flash = (char *)A ; D = *Adr_Flash ;
/*подстановка вместо функции R_Flash следующих выражений: Adr_Flash принимает значение А с 
явной сменой типа на указатель char?.,  Аргумент D принимает значение указателя Adr_Flash, 
т.е. на выходе я получаю Adr_Flash = char * A, D = char * A или я что-то неправильно понимаю?*/

#define W_Flash(A, D)      Adr_Flash = (char *)A ; *Adr_Flash = D ;
/*подстановка вместо функции R_Flash следующих выражений: Adr_Flash принимает значение А с 
явной сменой типа на указатель char?., указатель Adr_Flash принимает значение D*/

В общем то у меня в голове каша от такого синтаксиса. Возможно кто-то поймет что здесь происходит и сможет прокомментировать, буду благодарен. Под каждой из строк написал, как я понимаю происходящее.

Здесь вообще ничего не происходит - нужен код, который это использует. Первый макро R_Flash читает D по адресу A. Второй (почему то же имя?) записывает D по адресу A. volatile гарантирует, что про каждом вызове R_Flash будет происходить обращение к памяти. Стандартная практика в embedded.

@AlexF , исправил R_Flash на W_Flash. То есть я правильно понял, что по сути при вызове R_Flash(A, D) A служит просто адресом в памяти, а D получаемым по этому адресу значением? Сами макросы R_Flash & W_Flash находятся в функциях чтения и записи значений в память соответственно.

Да, правильно. Точнее, D это имя переменной, в которую записывается значение. Посмотрите документацию на свой компайлер, и прочитайте код после препроцессора. Там все макро раскрываются.
